# Why did the R function I built produce the wrong output?

Tags: r, function

I built an R function that produces the wrong output. Here is a simplified version:

```
# Dataset
test <- data.frame( color = c("blue", "green", "black", "white", "gray", "purple"))
test$color <- as.character(test$color)

# Build function to recode values which matches the input into a new output
fun_recode <- function(regex_input, regex_output) {
     reg_start <- ".*"
     reg_end <- ".*"
     index <- vector()
     for (i in 1:length(regex_input))  {
          index_1 <- grep(pattern = paste0(reg_start, regex_input[i], reg_end), x = test$color)
          index <- c(index, index_1)
     }
     test[index, ] <- regex_output
}

# Set arguments
regex_input <- c("a", "y")
regex_output <- "GOT IT!"

# Call function
fun_recode(regex_input, regex_output)
```

I get this output (noting changed):

[image]

The correct output should be:

[image]

Please advise what is wrong with my function. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Objects changed in the function do not get reflected in the global environment unless you use `<<-` or `assign` which is not recommended anyway.
2. You can collapse `regex_input` into one string to avoid using `for` loop.
3. There is no need for `reg_start` and `reg_end`. Also, it is better to pass dataframe explicitly into the function.

Try this function :

```
fun_recode <- function(data, regex_input, regex_output) {
  data$color[grep(paste0(regex_input, collapse = "|"), data$color)] <- regex_output
  return(data)
}

# Set arguments
regex_input <- c("a", "y")
regex_output <- "GOT IT!"

# Call function
test1 <- fun_recode(test,regex_input, regex_output)
test1
#    color
#1    blue
#2   green
#3 GOT IT!
#4   white
#5 GOT IT!
#6  purple
```

So the thing which is wrong in your function is point 1. The change done in the function remains in the function. You need to `return` the changed value from the function.